# Django: Mail not getting sent through view

Tags: python, django, email, gmail

I am trying to send my mail through django views but it is getting printed in console and I am not getting any mails in my mailbox, but when I tried through same settings from python shell I get the mail.

Settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mygmailusername@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mygmailpassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'mygmailusername@gmail.com'
```

views.py:

```
def login_view(request):
    #print (request.user.is_authenticated())
    title="Sign in"
    form=UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password=form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user=authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        subject='Test registration'
        message='New user registered.\n Welcome to DD.'
        from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        to_list=[user.email, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
        send_mail(subject,message,from_email,to_list,fail_silently=True)
        login(request,user)
       # print (request.user.is_authenticated())
        return redirect("/index")

    return render(request, "form.html", {"form": form, "title" : title})
```

Just for testing purposes I have kept it in login view.

Thanks!!!

Comment: i think you have double `EMAIL_BACKEND` in the `settings` just add `print(settings.EMAIL_BACKEND)`

Comment: set `fail_silently=False` to see if any exception

Comment: `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Test registration
From: sarthak.tuteja91@gmail.com
To: sarthak.tuteja91@gmail.com, sarthak.tuteja91@gmail.com
Date: Tue, 17 Jul 2018 06:50:30 -0000
Message-ID: <20180717065030.5690.4187@ip-172-31-13-68.us-east-2.compute.internal>

New user registered.
 Welcome to DD.`

This got printed

Comment: Same results with `fail_silently=False`

Comment: @SarthakTuteja and here the answer `django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend ` you have double set for `EMAIL_BACKEND`

Comment: Can you please explain a bit or change my code so that it works?

Comment: Got it, EMAIL_BACKEND was configured twice, that's why it was printing in console after I removed, it worked although now I am getting `SMTPAuthenticationError at /login/` error but you solution worked. Thanks!